# dotnet test is not running on csproj

Tags: azure-devops

We are running a local azure devops server. Since the last microsoft patch day the dotnet test fails:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

When i start the dotnet test on the server direct the dotnet test fails with the same csproj-file. Do i start the dotnet test without specifying the csproj-file, but in the same folder, it runs and the tests succeed. When i start the command line from visual studio tools it runs. Any ideas?

And here is the YAML:
steps:

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet test '
  inputs:
  command: test
  projects: |
  **/*Test*.csproj
  arguments: '-c  Release'
  testRunTitle: 'Test'
  enabled: false
  continueOnError: true

Comment: Do you mean you run a pipeline with [DotNetCoreCLI@2 task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive#run-your-tests) using Azure DevOps Server? Please provide your YAML definition.

Comment: You need to specify the test project like '**/*Tests/*.csproj' in the task. Otherwise, the task may just run empty and not test any projects.